# Unpivot Data and Separate Integers and Strings in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

[image]

Above is my current input.

Below is the desired output.

[image]

Currently, i load the data into Power Bi, and using the Power Query Editor I 'unpivot columns' on 'selected columns only'. This results in a column of mixed data types (Integers and strings). Is anyone able to advise an efficient method upon data load how to separate string values and integers?

[image]

Below is the code from Advanced Editor

```
let
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("F:\Surveys\dev\pivottest.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"responseid", Int64.Type}, {"q1", Int64.Type}, {"q2", type text}, {"q3", Int64.Type}, {"q4", type text}}),
#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Changed Type", {"q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"}, "Attribute", "Value") 
in
#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have unpivoted your data, then use the function [Value.Is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/value-is) on your **Value** column. To check if a value is number, it would look something like this:

```
Value.Is([Column], Int64.Type)

Example, 
IsNumber =Value.Is(Value.FromText([ColumnOfMixedValues]), type number)
```

To check for a text, it would be:

```
Value.Is([Column],type text)

Example,
IsText =Value.Is(Value.FromText([ColumnOfMixedValues]), type text)
```

Value.Is returns a boolean true/false, so you can wrap it in an IF.

```
if Value.Is(AlphaNumeric, type text) then AlphaNumeric else Number.ToText(AlphaNumeric))
```